# IIS auto-generated webpage listing all websites being hosted

Tags: iis, appcmd

Essentially what the title says. Is there a feature-of/addon-for IIS which allows presenting in a single web page a list with links pointing to the websites hosted within IIS?

I know I can get said list from the command line via:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site > c:\sites.xls
```

This will then create an Excel spreadsheet with the list of sites in IIS + site related information for each site.

But then I will have to parse the CSV file and turn it into html. This would work, but I'ld rather dodge it altogether if there already is a feature or an addon for the exact same thing out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Powershell for this: you can loop through IIS sites, virtual directories, web applications and dynamically build a simple html page.

Here is a simple script that creates an html file with a list of links to each virtual directory or web application. This is only a base script, you can customize it and add more details:

```ps
#Import WebAdministration to manage IIS contents
Import-Module WebAdministration

#define a variable that will hold your html code
$html = "<html>`n<body>"

#define the root path of your sites (in this example localhost)
$rootFolder = "http://localhost"

$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites 

#loop on all websites inside IIS
foreach($Site in $Websites)
{
    $VDirs = Get-WebVirtualDirectory -Site $Site.name
    $WebApps = Get-WebApplication -Site $Site.name

    #loop on all virtual directories    
    foreach ($vdir in $VDirs )
    {
    $html += "`n<a href='" + $rootFolder + $vdir.path +"'>" + $vdir.path + "</a><br/>"
    }
    #loop on all web applications
    foreach ($WebApp in $WebApps)
    { 
    $html += "`n<a href='" + $rootFolder + $WebApp.path +"'>" + $WebApp.path + "</a><br/>"
    }
}
#add final tags to html
$html += "`n</body>`n</html>"

#write html code to file
$html >> "d:\sites.html"
```

For example with this IIS structure:

[image]

you get the following html:

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href='http://localhost/vd'>/vd</a><br/>
<a href='http://localhost/test'>/test</a><br/>
<a href='http://localhost/test2'>/test2</a><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

that renders like this:

[image]